# How can I configure TeXstudio to use Arara automatically?

Tags: texstudio, arara

How can I convince TeXstudio to use Arara automatically?  I have the followings lines at the top of my LaTeX file:

```
%!TEX TS-program = Arara
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
```

when I hit F5 resp. the "create and show" button TeXstudio tells me:

```
Prozess gestartet: Arara
Prozess endete normal
```

and not compiling the file. I doubt that arara.exe had been called, as no arara-specific output was shown. I have set the user commands in advanced mode, so calling it via Shift-Alt-F1 works. What is necessary to make TeXstudio recognize the magic line automatically?

[image]

Comment: Your are on windows. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with a similar problem